# Using qTip with ASP.NET MVC unobtrusive javascript validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, qtip2

on the new jQuery qTip page, there is a really awesome sample of using it with jQuery Unobtrusive Validation, which can be found [here](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#validation)

In ASP.NET MVC 3.0, we have the unobtrusive validation as part of the view helpers. I was wondering if anyone knew how to implement this incredible thing in that, since I have not been able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](http://www.pieterg.com/Post/Posts/2010/3) is to an article describing how to integrate the `jquery.validationEngine.js` plugin with `jquery.validate.js`.

The line number references are slightly off, since they refer to older versions of jquery.validate.js.  However, you can use the points referenced to insert the code to have qTip balloons pop-up or disappear, based on validation done by jquery.validate.js.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I appreciate the link. I am not able to get to my web layer right now to try this, but will be back to it in a couple of hours. I'll dig around then and give it a try!

Comment: This worked really well. Thanks again. It took some fiddling, but I will post a `jsFiddle` when I get one complete.